# Upgrading groovy from 2.4 to 3.0 , why Intellij complains about could not resolve groovy-all-3.0.15-indy.jar?

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, invokedynamic

I am upgrading a Spring MVC application from Java 1.8 to Java 17. I have tried to update the groovy version from 2.4.x to 3.0.15. If I run the clean build, either from IntelliJ terminal or Mac command prompt, the build runs, but if I refresh using the Gradle refresh image shown on the gradle file, there is an update and the build fails with the following exception:

```
Could not find groovy-all-3.0.15-indy.jar (org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.15).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/3.0.15/groovy-all-3.0.15-indy.jar
```

I do understand that `indy.jar` is not part of groovy, but why is IntelliJ trying to get `indy.jar`?

I have tried to change `grooy-all` to `groovy`, but the build needs other dependencies which are bundled with `groovy-all`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I get groovy-all-4.0.0.jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71000075/where-can-i-get-groovy-all-4-0-0-jar)

Answer (score 2):

the groovy-all jar was deprecated from V2.5. The different libraries are split into separate jars. You can use the groovy-all Gradle pom dependency [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/3.0.15) if you want all.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71000075/where-can-i-get-groovy-all-4-0-0-jar).

[Indy](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/invokedynamic-support.html) (InvokeDynamic) has also been [dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54761358) because of a dependency on a higher than 1.8 java version.

Comment: Thank you. looks like intellij behaving wired in my machine.